# Making a view fill the area after rotation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, android-orientation

I am trying to use the [WaveView library](https://github.com/gelitenight/WaveView) in conjunction with the gyroscope values so that when I rotate the phone, I get the water flowing effect.
The library is just a view that I should ideally be able to control

The only problem is, when the WaveView rotates, it doesn't expand it's height and width to fill the blank area that's generated in the sides.
This happens even if I have given match_parent as the width.

Is there a way to get this working?

When the phone is not rotated, the view works perfectly:
[Screenshot with no rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjC3q.png)

But when the device and thus the view rotates, it looks like this, without the view filling the extra white space left in the sides and in the bottom:
[Screenshot with rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iFQB.png)

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must use framelayout with Your view in it. After rotation, You should re-create the view within the framelayout. I did it with a fragment like this:

```
FrameLayout mFragmentHolder = createFragmentHolder(angle);
            mMainLayout.removeAllViews();
            mMainLayout.addView(mFragmentHolder);
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            mFragMain = new FragmentMain();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(mFragmentHolder.getId(), mFragMain);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

And this is the createVieholder method:

```
private FrameLayout createFragmentHolder(int angle) {

        FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
        layout.setId(R.id.container);

        Point p = new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(p);

        int h = p.y;
        int w = p.x;

        LogUtil.d("size: " + h + " " + w);
        float delta = Math.abs(w - h);
        delta = delta / 2;
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = null;
        layout.setRotation(angle);
        if (angle == 0) {

            params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(w, h);
        } else if (angle == 90) {

            params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(h, w);
            layout.setPivotX((h / 2) + delta); // org +delta
            layout.setPivotY((w / 2));//+ delta
        } else if (angle == 180) {
            params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(w, h);
        } else if (angle == 270) {
            params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(h, w);
            layout.setPivotX((h / 2)); // org +delta
            layout.setPivotY((w / 2) - delta);//+ delta
        }
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
        LogUtil.d("created view");
        return layout;
    }
```

Not exactly the same situation as Yours, but this should help.
Note that in my case the device could not handle rotation by itself.